# How are Guild rewards distributed?

Tags: forge-of-empires

I've been trying to find out the distribution criteria (if it's known) of the rewards in Guild Battlegrounds for the Guild members.
Meaning: if the Guild's reward at the end of the Battlegrounds is 30 fragments of (for instance) the Statue of Honor, is every Guild member getting the same amount of fragments? Even though they made 0 points?

I've tried making 0 and 1 points in 2 different Battlegrounds and the fragments reward I received was the same, a smaller portion of the Guild reward (it was about 30 fragments in the first case and I got 9, and 23 fragments in the second case and I still got 9).

So I guess that there is some sort of cap (or ratio) based on the member's contribution. Does anybody know the specific criteria? I've tried looking it up but couldn't find results.

Edit: I might have made a mistake. It has been pointed out to me that I might have misread the number of fragments assigned at the end of the Battlegrounds. Since the number displayed is always one digit, it's possible that the number shown was "9+" and not just "9". If that's true (I'll verify at the end of the next GBG) I have probably got in both cases the total reward (30 and 23 fragments). Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that there's no assignment ratio depending on the member's contribution in the GBG. If a reward is given, everyone gets the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).